# Error:Connection timed out: connect

Tags: android, gradle, proxy

I changed the version of gradle of Android Studio 1.5.1 from 1.5 to 2.10 and clicked sync now, [(error image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3MVE.png) but the follow ERROR ocurred :

> Error:Connection timed out: connect. If you are behind an HTTP proxy, please configure the proxy settings either in IDE or Gradle.

Comment: although ans is same but you can also check this link [http://stackoverflow.com/a/37807663/2507782](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37807663/2507782)

Answer (score 14):

go to your gradle.properties file in gradle scripts and add this :

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1

systemProp.http.proxyPort=3128 // enter your proxy port

systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1

systemProp.https.proxyPort=3128 // enter your proxy port.
```

You can find proxy port by going to internet option-> connections -> LAN settings -> Advanced -> port

Comment: Thanks a lot in my case there are some lines I removed them and its start working.

Comment: how about Mac OS ?

Answer (score 1):

Incase you are still experiencing this error and not using any proxy, this is the way I solved my error by navigating to :

> `C:\Users\AdminUser\.gradle` then locate
> `gradle.properties`

deleted the code with proxy settings as below:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=proxyIP
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyHost=proxyIP
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
```